# after rendering, events not being shown in 24 hour format Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have started fullCalendar with such configurations as

```
  config: {
    plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, momentPlugin],
    // axisFormat: 'HH',
    slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    slotDuration: '00:60:00',
    columnFormat: 'dddd',
    columnHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'short' },
    defaultDate: '1970-01-01',
    dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    eventLimit: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
    eventColor: '#458CC7',
    firstDay: 1,
    height: 'auto',
    selectHelper: true,
    selectable: true,
    timezone: 'UTC',
    header: {
      left: '',
      center: '',
      right: ''
    },
    editable: true,
    events: null,
    eventTimeFormat: { // like '14:30:00'
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      meridiem: false
    }
  },
```

and I am trying to show events with start and end time with 24 Hour format. but they are being rendered in 12 Hour format. Below is the output I am getting currently and the last image is the output I actually want.

[image]

This is how events are being rendered to Calendar.

```
renderEvents () {
  const schedule = JSON.parse(this.schedule)
  const calendarWeek = this.currentCalendarWeek()
  const days = Object.keys(schedule)

  days.forEach((weekDay) => {
    const day = schedule[weekDay]
    if (day.length != 0) {
      day.forEach((event) => {
        const start = event.split('-')[0]
        const end = event.split('-')[1]

        const addEvent = {
          id: this.generate_random_string(4),
          start: moment(`${calendarWeek[weekDay]} ${start}`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')._i,
          end: moment(`${calendarWeek[weekDay]} ${end}`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')._i
        }
        this.calendar.addEvent(addEvent)
      })
    }
  })
},
```

and this.schedule is

```
  schedule: JSON.stringify({
    Monday: ['08:00-18:00'],
    Tuesday: ['08:00-18:00'],
    Wednesday: ['08:00-18:00'],
    Thursday: ['08:00-18:00'],
    Friday: ['08:00-18:00'],
    Saturday: [],
    Sunday: []
  }),
```

Even on adding a new event. it doesnt come as 24 hour time format

How I can get output like this instead.

[image]

Comment: so what result are you getting currently? It's not really clear.

Comment: didnt you see the picture in question? which showing the events being rendered?

Comment: Yes I did. Is that the output you want, or the output you get currently? Either way it's not clear. You have not shown both cases. Please show clearly what output you get now, **and** what output you want instead.

Comment: I have updated an image how I want the output, thanks for the heads up. Any help would be thankful?

Comment: Thanks. That is clearer now. I think I can help. But...you really want to it to show 16:59 as the end time? Surely it should be 18:00, based on your data, and the other screenshot?

Comment: Anyway I added an answer. (BTW, if you'd looked at what you'd done for `slotLabelFormat`, you'd realise the solution was already right there in front of you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a 24-hour format, you have two ways to do it.

You can either

1) Set the `hour12: false` option in your eventTimeFormat, e.g.

```
eventTimeFormat: {
  hour: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit",
  hour12: false
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxwdNYa

(The [eventTimeFormat documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat) does describe this, but a bit inaccurately / unclearly. The general fullCalendar [date formatting documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting) makes it much clearer though, if you check there.)

**OR**

2) Since you're already using the momentJS plugin (and already using it to set the time format of your slots), you could use the simple time format identical to the one you've already set for `slotLabelFormat`:

```
eventTimeFormat: "HH:mm"
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKdmLbv